# Generic type that taps on functions inputs and outputs

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.0

Given:

```
type SomeService = {
    someFunction:      (i: string) => number
    someOtherFunction: (i: string) => string[]
}
```

I want to have a generic type that results in:

```
type SomePromisifiedService = {
    someFunction:      (i: string) => Promise<number>
    someOtherFunction: (i: string) => Promise<string[]>
}
```

Here's some pseudo-code that maybe better explains this:

```
type PromisifyResults<T extends {}> = 
    { [k in keyof T]: (...T[k].args) => Promise<T[k].output> }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) added in typescript 2.8 and [generic rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters) (typescript 3.0):

```
type PromisifyResults<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer R
        ? (...args: Args) => Promise<R>
        : T[K]
}
```

[Try in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20SomeService%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someFunction%3A%20(i%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someOtherFunction%3A%20(i%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someOtherFunction2%3A%20(i%3A%20string%2C%20f%3A%20boolean)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bstring%2C%20boolean%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PromisifyResults%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20infer%20Args)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20(...args%3A%20Args)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CR%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%5BK%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SomePromisifiedService%20%3D%20PromisifyResults%3CSomeService%3E)

Comment: @Birowsky see updated answer - simplified and not limited on functions argument count